# script error - requireJS

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js, requirejs

I am using requireJS to load `xchart.js` that depends on `d3.js`, and I keep on having this message error `Uncaught Error: Script error for: d3`

```
    require({
        paths:{
            'd3': 'vendor/charts/d3.min',
            'charter': 'vendor/charts/xcharts.min'
        }
    },['js/vendor/charts/charter.js'],function(App){
        App.initial_charter();
    });
```

and in `js/vendor/charts/charter.js`, I put

```
define(['d3','charter'],function(){
        function initial_charter(){
            ...
}return{
            initial_charter: initial_charter
        }
    }
);
```

so I tried

```
require(['js/vendor/charts/d3.min.js'],function(){
        require({
            paths:{
                'charter': 'vendor/charts/xcharts.min'
            }
        },['js/vendor/charts/charter.js'],function(App){
            App.initial_charter();
        });
    });
```

and I still get the same error message

Update : I didn't change anything and now in my console `xChart is not defined`
Rmk : I find `requireJS` really unstable, is it me or known ?

Comment: It's not really clear what your actual module files are from your examples. Is the `'charter'` path that maps to `'vendor/charts/xcharts.min'` the same file as `'js/vendor/charts/charter.js'`? Think you need to pull out all your requirejs config into an initialisation statement that is done before all your other requirejs usage.

Answer (score 1):

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddlegrimbo/3DDhc/1/) will load d3:

```
<script>
require = {
    paths: {
        "d3": "https://rawgithub.com/mbostock/d3/v3.3.4/d3"
    },
    shim: {
        "d3": {
            exports: "d3"
        }
    }
};
</script>
<script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.8/comments/require.js"></script>
<script>
require(["d3"], function (d3) {
    console.log.apply(console, arguments);
});
</script>
```

Outputs to console:

```
Object {version: "3.3.4", ascending: function, descending: function, min: function, max: function…}
```